# How to pass the entire object from jsp to spring controller

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC and hope someone can help me figure out this issue. I have jsp like this:

```
  <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="50">Id</td>
    <td width="150">First Name</td>
    <td width="150">Last Name</td>
    <td width="50">Money</td>
    <td width="50"></td>
  </tr>
       <c:forEach items="${persons}" var="person">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${person.id}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${person.firstName}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${person.lastName}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${person.money}" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">  <a href="<c:url value="removeContact" />">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>

      </c:forEach>
</table>
```

When user clicks on the Delete link, I want to pass the entire object (person) to the controller. Can someone please help how would I do that? I will appreciate any help.

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/removeContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String removeContact(@ModelAttribute("contact")Person person, BindingResult result) {
    System.out.println("============ > "+person.getId());

  return "index.jsp";
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't use permit delete operation on GET requests. Use DELETE instead, it's more appropriate. If you use jquery, use the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function to submit your data to the controller.